# Passing value of textarea with jquery to PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have a tip section that can be "custom" input from a customer. When the customer enters a value, I want to pass it to PHP for updating the order.

I'm unsuccessful and I'm thinking I'm approaching this problem the wrong way since I can't get it to work. What options are available to me without using AJAX?

The tip section:

```
  <?= ($receipt['tip'] > 0 ?
  '<tr id="tip-area"><th>Tip</th>
    <td><textarea id="tip" name="update_tip" readonly>'. $receipt['tip'].'</textarea></td>
  </tr>'
  : '') ?>
```

My form which has different tip options:

```
    <form method="post">
      <tr>
        <button title="20% Tip" type="submit" name="update_tip" id="update_tip" class="tip-button"
                value="<?= ($_SESSION['order']['quote']['subtotal'] * 0.2); ?>">
          <small>20%<br><?= number_format(($_SESSION['order']['quote']['subtotal'] * 0.2), 2) ?></small>
        </button>

        <button title="Edit Tip" type="button" name="update_tip" id="custom-tip" class="tip-button">
          <small>Edit<br>Tip<br></small>
        </button>

        <button title="Save Tip" type="submit" id="save_tip" class="hidden">
          <small>Save<br>Tip</small>
        </button>
      </tr>
    </form>
```

My jQuery:

```
  $('#custom-tip').click(function(){
    $('#tip').removeAttr('readonly').focus();
    $('.tip-button').addClass("hidden");
    $('#save_tip').removeClass("hidden");
  });

  $('#save_tip').click(function (){
    var tip = $('textarea#tip').val();
    $('<input type="hidden" name="update_tip" value="' + tip + '">').submit();
  });

  $('#tip').focus(function(){
    this.value = '';
  });
```

When they press "Edit Tip", the `readonly` property is remove, the area comes into focus and value is cleared.

Then the user should enter a value and hit `Save`.

Then I'm trying to retrieve the value they entered.

Comment: Your form tag does not have an action attribute. What page are you submitting the form values to ?

Comment: Where is the PHP code that processes the values  and saves them? That would be the same PHP page to which you want to submit your form.

Comment: Note: $('<input type="hidden" name="update_tip" value="' + tip + '">').submit();   That line right there is **creating** a brand new input that is detached from the DOM (doesn't exist on the page yet) and then tries to submit it.

Comment: @Taplar - that's correct. I'm trying to create that and submit it inside the form where the button is located. The tip section is in a table that is outside the form.

Comment: @Maximus2012 - The different sections are broken up in functions so I can't submit to page, it won't pick up the POST. Am I approaching this problem incorrectly? Should I use AJAX instead?

Comment: So question.  Do you, or do you not, want to do this with AJAX?  Meaning do you want to do this when they change it, or do you want to do this when they submit the/a form?

Comment: @Taplar - I'm trying to avoid using AJAX and submit it with the button by creating a new element which gets the value from the textarea.

Comment: You can't have `<form>` around `<tr>`. `<tr>` has to be a child of `<table>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, or `<tfoot>`. You need to put `<form>` around the entire `<table>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $("<input>", {
        type: "hidden",
        name: "update_tip",
        value: $("#tip").val()
    }).appendTo($(this));
});
```

This will create the hidden input with the value from the textarea and append it to the current form when before the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have PHP code on the same page (because your form does not specify an action) that handles the data. Use the 'name' attribute for your input to specify the key of the value you wish to access in the $_POST super global. For example, if I post a form with the following code:

```
<form method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' value='hello' name='world'>
    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

Then in PHP, I can access the value of the element with the name "world" with the following code:

`$_POST['world']`

Use this syntax to acquire the data from the form and persist it/update it.

Comment: The tip section is in a table that is outside the form - I was hoping to use jQuery to bypass that limitation.

Comment: If you give the element an ID, you can access it via jQuery selectors. So if the hidden element had an id of `tip`, you could set the value of that element using `$("#tip").val(<value of tip>);` So you use a handler to check if the value of the user input change, and dynamically change the value of the function with the code above.